# Zalando Problem always returns 404 from controlleradvice

Tags: spring, exception

I have a Spring ControllerAdvice using Zalando Problem dependency. On making an http request using Postman, I can see the breakpoint enter the if condition below, but the http response returned is always a 404. What can I do to make it return an http 400 bad request response like the Problem object built below.

```
    @Slf4j
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class MyExceptionHandler {
        @ExceptionHandler(ExceptionClassA.class)
        public Problem exceptionClassA(final ExceptionClassA e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(e.getCause()) && e.getCause() instanceof ExceptionClassB) {
                return Problem.builder()
                        .withTitle("Error A")
                        .withDetail(e.getCause().getMessage())
                        .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .build();
            }
            return Problem.builder()
                    .withTitle("Error B")
                    .withDetail(e.getMessage())
                    .withStatus(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the return type and wrapping the problem inside a ResponseEntity fixed the issue. Here is the full code -

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ExceptionClassA.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> exceptionClassA(final ExceptionClassA e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(e.getCause()) && e.getCause() instanceof ExceptionClassB) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                    .body(Problem.builder()
                            .withTitle("Error A")
                            .withDetail(e.getCause().getMessage())
                            .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                            .build());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
                .body(Problem.builder()
                        .withTitle("Error B")
                        .withDetail(e.getMessage())
                        .withStatus(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .build());
    }
}
```